# What is the shortest way C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, winforms

I am new to C#. I have a table called invoicemaster. When I am generating a new invoice number I use below code. If someone is cleared a invoice in a multi user environment, I put 'Y' in iscleared column and use that invoice number for the next invoice. Otherwise I generate invoice number by adding 1 to the max number. I have two issues.

1. Is there a short way to write this code.
2. When I try to get the MIN(invno), it returns a null value and rows.count show as 1. But there is no record in the table. How to prevent that?

```
int intInvNo = 0;
sql = "SELECT MIN(invno) FROM invoicemaster WHERE `iscleared`='Y'";
config.singleResult(sql);

if (config.dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   intInvNo = Convert.ToInt32(config.dt.Rows[0].Field<int>(0).ToString());
}
else
{
   sql = "SELECT MAX(invno) FROM invoicemaster";
   config.singleResult(sql);

   if (config.dt.Rows.Count > 0)
   {
      intInvNo = Convert.ToInt32(config.dt.Rows[0].Field<int>(0).ToString()) + 1;
   }
}

lblInvNo.Text= String.Format("{0,12:00000000}", intInvNo);
```

Comment: is this a WPF/WinForms application or a web application?

Comment: Are you sure that's valid? In most circumstances I'm aware of, Invoice numbers should remain uniquely assigned even if the invoice was later cancelled/destroyed/etc.

Comment: you should reconsider your logic. this way you'll assign the same invoice numbers multiple times. can't you just set the invoice number as autoincrement in sql?

Comment: Is this a SQL Server table?  If so, make the column an `Identity` column and it will auto-increment for you.  Managing an incrementing number like this on your own in a multi-user environment is challenging.

Comment: WinForms application with MySQL

Comment: In my locale, this would be highly illegal. (As in: If there is a tax-audit, you'll be out-of-business _instantly_).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever can confirm - in germany, invoice numbers _must_ be unique.

Comment: If I make auto increment, there will be empty invoices or it will not make a sequence, when delete a invoice. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do the invoice numbers have to be sequential? Why are you not able to skip a number in a sequence? It seems like a nonsensical requirement or interpretation.

Comment: There's even an argument that things like sequential invoice numbers leak potentially sensitive information, such as how much business you're doing, and non-consecutive (**but still unique!**) numbers are better

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I changed my mind to go with auto increment.

Comment: @canton7 this is also known as [German Tank Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem)

Comment: @Igor - "Why do the invoice numbers have to be sequential" - e.g. in Germany invoice numbers MUST* be sequential. (*you must be able to explain missing numbers)

Comment: Then what is the solution to prevent that missing numbers?